# Lazy load images on Hugo

Tags: lazy-loading, hugo

I am trying to lazy load images on my hugo website.

I downloaded the npm plugin `lazyload` by typing: `npm i lazyload`.

In my code if I follow the documentation, I just have to write:
`<img class="lazyload" data-src="image.jpg" width="765" height="574" />`

When I am doing that, the image is not displaying anymore, I think it is because of the `data-src`.
But without the `data-src` I can't do a lazyload. So it is very confused.

Comment: Have you included, configured, and initialised that `lazyload` library, as per their instructions? Be sure the `<script src="whatever/lazyload">...` is included in the page's `<head>`.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the tag `loading=lazy` will work in the newer versions of most modern browsers.